# Как развернуть в Docker каждый инстанс кластера Tarantool в отдельном контейнере?

Tags: docker, tarantool

На основе https://github.com/tarantool/docker я описал docker-compose.yml для поднятия одного инстанса Tarantool.

```html
version: '2'

services:
  tarantool:
    image: tarantool:1.0.0
    environment:
      TARANTOOL_INSTANCE_NAME: 'tarantool'
      TARANTOOL_ADVERTISE_URI: '3302'
      TARANTOOL_CLUSTER_COOKIE: 'secret'
      TARANTOOL_USER_NAME: 'admin'
      TARANTOOL_USER_PASSWORD: 'secret'
      TARANTOOL_HTTP_PORT: '8082'
    networks:
      - private_network
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
      - 3302:3302
```

Но я хочу поднять и другие инстансы кластера в Docker, желательно каждый в отдельном контейнере. Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Даже в Вашей ссылке на гитхаб есть примеры) Просто допишите нужное кол-во инстансов в `services` с разными названиями.

Вот пример master-master replica set:

```
version: '2'

services:
  tarantool1:
    image: tarantool/tarantool:1.10.2
    environment:
      TARANTOOL_REPLICATION: "tarantool1,tarantool2"
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - "3301:3301"

  tarantool2:
    image: tarantool/tarantool:1.10.2
    environment:
      TARANTOOL_REPLICATION: "tarantool1,tarantool2"
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - "3302:3301"

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```